# Recover mysql innodb with frm files

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-restore, frm

I need to recover a full database, I have the whole mysql folder but copying and pasting has not worked for me.

In folder of database I have .frm files and .opt files.

I have also ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata1.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-backup.html
It says here that also need my.cnf, but I don't have.

Thanks.

Comment: Recover from what exactly? I've had some luck in the past with (re)installing a MySQL server, shutting it down, replacing the new install's data directory with a copy of the original, and starting the server process up again... but as always, don't "use up" your only backup in the process (i.e. copy not move). (Also, I don't recall for sure, but it is probably best to pick as close to the same install settings as on the original as/if possible; down to the same paths even.)

Comment: if you are using InnoDB storage engine, Where are your .ibd files?

Comment: How was my.cnf created originally?  Walk through those steps.  The big item that could cause trouble is `innodb_log_file_size`; it must match the size of the iblog* files.